# Android set selected listview item highlighted with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need your help. My problem is that I need to highlight the selected listview item. Note that it only needs to set single item, not multiple.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
  @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.background = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.background);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    result = new HashMap<>();
    result = data.get(position);

    if(firstTimeStartup && position == 0) { // default selected
        result = data.get(0);
        highlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
    } else {
        unhighlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result = data.get(position);

            if (firstTimeStartup) { // first time  highlight first row
                firstTimeStartup = false;
                result = data.get(0);
                unhighlight(viewHolder.background, 0);
            }

            highlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
    });

    return convertView;

}

private void unhighlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
}

private void highlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.main_blue);
}

private Boolean firstTimeStartup = true;
```

But the problem is I couldn't unhighlight the item when I clicked the convertView. Also the default (first) item is not unhighlighting when I tried to click other items. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result = data.get(position);

        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
              if(i == position){
                      highlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
                  }
                else{
                    unhighlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
                     }
              }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

create a method like this :

```
CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

int selectedPosition=0;

  @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 if(position==selectedPosition){
   highlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
 }else{
     unhighlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
 }




 }

  void highlightUnhighlight(int position){

 seslectedPostion= postion;
 notifyDatasetChanged

 }
 }
```

Call highlightUnhighlight(postion) in onItemClickListener.

Comment: How about when I select the row?

Comment: When u select a row that means your on item click is called and you will highlight current row and unhighlight all other rows.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code ,please check this code may be your problem will solve. I used this code in my project.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewHolder viewHolder;

if(convertView == null) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video_item, parent, false);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.background = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.background);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

result = new HashMap<>();
result = data.get(position);

if(firstTimeStartup[position]) { // default selected
    result = data.get(0);
    highlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
} else {
    unhighlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
}

convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result = data.get(position);

        if (firstTimeStartup[position]) { 
            Arrays.fill(firstTimeStartup, Boolean.FALSE);
            firstTimeStartup[position] = false;
            result = data.get(0);
            unhighlight(viewHolder.background, 0);
        }else{
        Arrays.fill(firstTimeStartup, Boolean.FALSE);
        firstTimeStartup[position] = true;
        highlightCurrentRow(viewHolder.background);
        }

   notifyDataSetChanged();
});

return convertView;
}

private void unhighlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
rowView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
}

private void highlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.main_blue);
}

 private Boolean firstTimeStartup[] = new Boolean[data.size()];
 firstTimeStartup[0]=true;
```

Comment: Hi this works partly, but the default selected does not unhighlight when I click on other items.

Comment: It should only select one item at a time. Item only gets unhighlighted when you click it once again. This should not be.